# Pushing value into the session array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code where the user selects the value from a drop down. Everytime they submit, the ID should be pushed in the array.

```
<?php
$_SESSION["test"] = array();
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbsikkim",$link);
?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT ID,DOC_DESC FROM gstn_document_type_master",$link);
echo "<select name='doc_type_code2'>";
  if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
       echo "<option value=".$row['ID'].">".$row['DOC_DESC']."</option>";
  }
}
echo "</select>";
?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $_SESSION["test"][] = $_POST['doc_type_code2'];  //ERROR IN THIS LINE

 for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($_SESSION["test"]); $i++) {
                            echo $_SESSION["test"][$i]."<br>";
                            }

}
?>
```

Only the current value is pushed into the array and replaces the previous one. In simple words, it is working as a variable and not an array.

Comment: Each time you click the submit button the page reloads, and when the page reloads the variables are are redefined. Losing it's value. So try to use some other options like $_SESSION.

Answer (score -1):

You most likely need to get your session variable initialized.

$_SESSION["test"] is not an array by default. You could try to do:

```
// If the session variable is not yet an array, initialize it
if (!is_array($_SESSION["test"])) {
   $_SESSION["test"] = [];
}

$_SESSION["test"][] = $_POST['doc_type_code2'];
```

The first line assigns an array to your field. 
The second one assigns a value to the array.

Please note, there are several things to improve in your code. In example, you could use PDO these days. Also you should not use "global". Also mixing PHP and HTML code like that might lead to software which is hard to maintain. I don't want to sound arrogant, but I highly recommend you the book ["PHP The right way"](http://www.phptherightway.com/).

Comment: You won't want to do `$_SESSION["test"] = [];` each time as it will reset the array. Something like `if (!is_array($_SESSION["test"])) $_SESSION["test"] = [];` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Agreed @Steve. I will update my response.

Comment: @Christian Thanks for responding and your valueable feedback. But here, I have already declared the array as $test = array(); in the beginning. Also your $_SESSION["test"] = []; shows parse error.

Comment: @Amir Bhandari You're probably using an older version of PHP, try `$_SESSION["test"] = array()`. Also, declaring `$test = array();` will not affect the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: Yes I did that. Now the code has been modified. It is not showing any error but only single value is passed on to array and replaced everytime I submit.

Comment: If you're using Christian's updated code your array should increase in size on each submission.

Comment: In your current posted code, update your first line to `if (!is_array($_SESSION["test"])) $_SESSION["test"] = array();`